# Run C# function after two ASP TextBoxes have been filled

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I've been all over trying to find an answer to this, but every answer I found seemed to differ quiet a bit from what I really am looking for.

I need to check to make sure that two ASP Textboxes have been filled in before running a C# function that will do work on the text boxes.

Currently, I am using codebehind to check, but it is sloppy and has to postback to work.

So I have:

```
<td>Start Date (mm/dd/yyyy):</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="startDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="ce1" runat="server" TargetControlID="startDate"></ajax:CalendarExtender>

                <td>End Date (mm/dd/yyyy):</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="endDate"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="ce2" runat="server" TargetControlID="endDate"></ajax:CalendarExtender>
```

So I need a JS function to check if both field are empty, before using AJAX to run a C# program. I'm new to ASP and JS but this problem came through and figured it would be a (sort of) easy fix.

I would assume something like:

```
function checkDates(startid, endid) {
    var s = document.getElementById(startid);
    var e = document.getElementById(endid);
    if( s != '' && e != ''){
       //Use ajax to run C# function
    }}
```

should work. But I can't seem to find any examples close to it to get an idea of what I need to do when working ASP and not just HTML.

Any input is greatly appreciated! (I tried to be as clear as possible, getting tunnel vision..)

Comment: Your TextBox control tags look to be malformed. (first one is missing a closing bracket) You don't have 'runat="server"' specified.

Comment: Thanks! I must have accidentally hit a delete key. I'm new to ASP so the  runat is still not ingrained ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there

```
function checkDates(startid, endid) {
  var s = document.getElementById(startid);
  var e = document.getElementById(endid);
  if( s.value != '' && e.value != ''){
     //Use ajax to run C# function
  }
}
```

You should also need to check on the server side to ensure that the parameters being supplied are not null or empty.

Comment: bah! I forgot the .value! But how can I send the ids from the ASP textbox to the JS functions? I've used alert() to try to see if any methods work, but none of the combinations seem to work for me.

Comment: Use the `ClientID` property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: You would access the client id of the control in JavaScript in this format -> document.getElementById('<%=control.ClientID%>')

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.  I built an object to help keep things organized.  Get the elements using the ClientID and store the reference in an object.

Whatever you're binding the handler to just needs to call `Page.Handlers.CheckDates();`

```
var Page =
{
    Members:
    {
        startDate: document.getElementById('<%=startDate.ClientID %>'),
        endDate: document.getElementById('<%=endDate.ClientID %>')
    },
    Handlers:
    {
        CheckDates: function ()
        {
            if (Page.Members.startDate.value.length > 0 && Page.Members.endDate.value.length > 0)
            {
                Page.Ajax.ValidateDates();
            }
        }
    },
    Ajax:
    {
        ValidateDates: function ()
        {
            //Put you ajax code here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Kami's answer I believe asp.net automatically prepends a tag to all asp.net controls to distinguish them. If you haven't changed it yourself I believe the default is "ct100_". So if you're using jQuery and aren't use an ajax call to get the ClientID the selector would look something like "#ct100_idname".

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs

Edit:

You can also use an inline server call to get the ID of a asp.net control

http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx